# when am executing the below code am getting <terminated> WriteExcelFile[java application] error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

package seleniumpackage;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class WriteExcelFile {

```
public void writeExcel(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName,String[] dataToWrite) throws IOException{

    //Create an object of File class to open xlsx file

    File file =    new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);

    //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    Workbook guru99Workbook = null;

    //Find the file extension by splitting  file name in substring and getting only extension name

    String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));

    //Check condition if the file is xlsx file

    if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")){

    //If it is xlsx file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class

    guru99Workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

    }

    //Check condition if the file is xls file

    else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")){

        //If it is xls file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class

        guru99Workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

    }    

//Read excel sheet by sheet name    

Sheet sheet = guru99Workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

//Get the current count of rows in excel file

int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();

//Get the first row from the sheet

Row row = sheet.getRow(0);

//Create a new row and append it at last of sheet

Row newRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount+1);

//Create a loop over the cell of newly created Row

for(int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++){

    //Fill data in row

    Cell cell = newRow.createCell(j);

    cell.setCellValue(dataToWrite[j]);

}

//Close input stream

inputStream.close();

//Create an object of FileOutputStream class to create write data in excel file

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

//write data in the excel file
System.out.println(file);

guru99Workbook.write(fos);

//close output stream

fos.close();

}

public static void main(String...strings) throws IOException{

    //Create an array with the data in the same order in which you expect to be filled in excel file

    String[] dataToWrite = {"Mr. E","Noida"};

    System.out.println(dataToWrite);
    //Create an object of current class

    WriteExcelFile objExcelFile = new WriteExcelFile();

    //Write the file using file name, sheet name and the data to be filled

    objExcelFile.writeExcel(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\excelExportAndFileIO","ExportExcel.xlsx","ExcelGuru99Demo",dataToWrite);

}
```

}

Comment: Share the full exception

Answer (score 3):

I went through the code and tried running it, and got the same message in the console. But it isn't an error actually.

More specifically it is giving message as: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\javaw.exe (Sep 24, 2019, 4:00:39 PM)

In above statement, "Terminated" means the program finished, and exit code 0 means "normal completion" So basically Eclipse says "your program is done."

Verify your excel, data you are trying to add must have been inserted.